# Hibernate Named Query or SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, named-query

I need to make either a named query or a stored procedure. This is running from a Java application that is attached to SQL Server through Hibernate. I would prefer a stored procedure, but a named query might suffice.

I have a table in SQL Server that has a column of XML type. This is not important in and of itself, but it's causing a problem.

My Hibnerate named query looks like this

```
<sql-query name="openOrderSummary" callable="true">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT * FROM orders
        WHERE (order_type in (:firstListOfTypes)
        OR order_type in (:secondListOfTypes))
        AND open_flag = 'true'
        AND customer_id = :customerId
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ]]>
</sql-query>
```

But an exception is thrown for this with a complaint of not being able to map JDBC type `-16`. This is not helpful. So I debugged through the Hibernate code and found that it has a problem with my XML typed column.

I preferred to do a stored procedure, but I couldn't find a non-screwy way (on my own) of doing the list of strings for the `order_type in (:firstListOfTypes)` part (and, by extension, the second list). This is not a fixed list. It is pulled from Java code and it could change at any time with new types being added, so I can't just make it a hardcoded list in the query.

I do the `select *` because I need the whole row. I'm doing either the named query or stored procedure because speed is a factor. Similar stored procedures (on a small subset of columns with very simple types) are so fast they appear to be instant. Running a normal fetch of this information through typical JDBC operations with `Session` and `Criteron` etc. takes several seconds. It may not seem like much, but in this application, it's important.

1) Is there a reasonable way to get this list from Java into a stored procedure?

2) If not, how can I get around Hibernate barfing when it comes to my xml column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reasonable way to get this list from Java into a stored procedure?

Sure.

Pass it as a comma-delimited list to a Varchar(max) or NVarchar(max) stored procedure argument and use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Pass it as a JSON array to a NVarchar(max) stored procedure argument and use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Pass it as an XML document to a Varchar(max) or NVarchar(max) stored procedure argument and use [xml.nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) (or the older [OPENXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

Comment: If I'm reading the compatibility level correctly, STRING_SPLIT and OPENJSON require at least SQL Server 2017? Compatibility level 130. What if clients have anything from 2008 on up?

Comment: OPENJSON and STRING_SPLIT require Compatibility level 130, on SQL Server 2016 or later.  The XML methods were introduced in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: It looks like I'll have to go the OPENXML route due to client needs. Do you have an example of what a stored procedure would look like if I have a simple XML array, of the format `<types><type>simplestringhere</type>{more elements here}</types>`?

Comment: I had to figure a lot of this out myself, but I got it working based on the hints in the answer. I went with `OPENXML` due to client needs where many of them use much older versions of SQL Server, where `STRING_SPLIT` and `OPENJSON` are not supported.

Comment: .....and I'm back at square one. I still get the `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -16`. Argh. So `2)` from above. I have this in a hibernate config file `    <sql-query name="sp_OpenOrdersSummary" callable="true">
        exec sp_OpenOrdersSummary :ordereId, :orderTypes
    </sql-query>`. I need the whole row returned, most especially that XML field. The field is already mapped properly higher up in the file with the other fields. Does special handling need to be declared in the sp call definition?

Comment: So is there an XML column in the table?  I don’t know hibernate, but can you cast it to nvarchar(max) and handle it outside Hibernate?

Comment: There is an XML column, yes. That's where Hibernate is barfing. In Hibernate, there is a map keyed by integers with a string as the value. This string is a database type that either Hibernate or the JDBC class (I forget which) is aware of. -16 is not in the map. When I put a breakpoint in the Hibernate jar, it seems that `xml`, `-16`, and `LONGNVARCHAR` all have to go together somehow, but the `-16` key is not present.